# how to get the tax data of some product in Shopify API

Tags: shopify-api, tax

We are using the "product" and "product variant" endpoints to import products from Shopify.

We have a problem in identifying the tax value of each product.

According to the API documentation each product variant has `tax_code` element, whose value is a key for available tax values.

Which endpoint can I use in order to find the value of this key `tax_code`?

Here for example, how can I know how much is the VAT amount of `tax_code`: "DA040000"?
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-10/resources/product-variant

I am using these two endpoints:
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-10/resources/product-variant
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-10/resources/product-variant

Even the country endpoint does not help:
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-04/resources/country#get-countries